# How to capture a screenshot in Unity v2021 to iOS device?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

My current code shows the following but it doesn't capture anything, the screen flashes, but no permission prompt, nor anything is saved.

```
IEnumerator TakeSnap() {

yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
        SnapTransparentBG.SetActive (true);
        SoundManager.instance.PlayClickSound ();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.125f);
        SnapTransparentBG.SetActive (false);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PHOTO
        // create the texture
        Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height,TextureFormat.RGB24,true);
        
        // put buffer into texture
        screenTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0f, 0f, Screen.width, Screen.height),0,0);
        
        // apply
        screenTexture.Apply();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PHOTO
        
        byte[] dataToSave = screenTexture.EncodeToPNG();
     destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".png");
        Debug.Log (destination);
        File.WriteAllBytes(destination, dataToSave);

}
```

Looking to make this work for iOS 10+ devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the default screen capture function?

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("Your path");
```

Your screenTexture is not reading any buffer, because you didn't assign any active render texture buffer for it.

If you want to capture the screen via render texture, you should pass the buffer to texture2d in this way:

```
    RenderTexture.active = rt;
    Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D(rt.width, rt.height);
    screenTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rt.width, rt.height), 0, 0);
    screenTexture.Apply();
```